# image effects iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

are there any tutorials for creating image effects in iphone? like glow,paper effect etc
Can anyone tell me where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A glow effect is not supported by default within the iPhone SDK (specifically CoreGraphics). For the paper effect I am not sure what you are looking for. 
If you insist on effects not supported by the SDK, you should try to find less platform specific sources and adapt them to the iPhone:

[Glow and Shadow Effects](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/Glow_and_Shadow_effects.aspx) (Windows GDI)

Another possibly great source of effect-know-how are the [ImageMagick sources](ftp://ftp.fifi.org/pub/ImageMagick/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this project: http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/

It includes code that can do various image effects such as canny edge detection, histogram equalisation, skeletonisation, thresholding, gaussian blur, brightness normalisation, connected region extraction, and resizing.

Another other more low level option is to take a look at [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) which are further image processing libraries.